# PHP escaping hexadecimal characters

Tags: php, hex, notation

I wrote a script that uses file_get_contents() to open files on server, path is delivered by POST. I only had to receive path from POST and use str_replace() to change "%2F" to "/". Everything worked fine until today. Now in some of supported paths php makes unescaped hexadecimal codes that cannot be supplied to file_get_contents().

Example:

```
2 parameters:
end = wypisZgierz/Łagiewniki Nowe Zachód/koncowe.htm
start = wypisZgierz/Łagiewniki Nowe Zachód/ogolne.htm
source:
start=wypisZgierz%2F%C5%81agiewniki+Nowe+Zach%C3%B3d%2Fogolne.htm&end=wypisZgierz%2F%C5%81agiewniki+Nowe
+Zach%C3%B3d%2Fkoncowe.htm
```

Start works fine, but end not.

```
PHP error log:
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(wypisZgierz/\xc5\x81agiewniki Nowe Zach\xc3\xb3d/koncowe.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

***EDIT 1 ***

Thanks to rawurldecode() I coul skip my str_replace(), but this doesn't help with original problem.

Real php code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$start = "";
$end = "";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($key == "start") {
        $start = $value;
        $start = str_replace("%2F","/",$start);}
    if($key == "end") {
        $end = $value;
        $end = str_replace("%2F","/",$end);
    }
}
$tempstart = file_get_contents($start);
$html = $tempstart;
$tempend = file_get_contents($end);
$html = $html.$tempend;
echo $html;
?>
```

The problem is that for old data it works fine, and now once $start and $end doesn't work, once only $start works. And if i supply start and end with the same value it still shows error with end (with start it might work or not). @pcdoc

Answer (score 1):

the php function rawurldecode should do the trick! But if you posted some real php code it'd be easier to determine your exact problem!